# Play console - Upload failed use a diffrent version of apk, already have one with version 1 - But I have version 2

Tags: android, build.gradle, apk, google-play-console

I have recently released an app. And now I'm trying to update it.

And I'm running into an issue. I get an error:

> Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK
> because you already have one with version code 1

Now I've done some research and tried various things, so here's a list of what I've found out, and tried:

I've changed the version code to many different things, and none work, it's the same error for all of them, if I set the version code to say 3, the error still says that I already have a file with version code 1, and it's never been anything else, never 2 or 3, always 1.
When I first uploaded the first version of the app, I had an error. And I fixed it, but then when uploading the new file, This same error showed up. But that was first after uploading one version, then deleting that and then the next once had this error. The way I got the app uploaded in the first place was that i made a new "app" on the google play console, and then uploaded the new file to that one. There it didn't have the error, but I'm sure it would have if I uploaded it twice.

But then now I need to upload a new version, and I kinda don't wanna make a new app, and I shouldn'
t have to.
So the first thing I tried after a bit of research was to go to another wifi, although our wifi is really good. I tried my phone hotspot, expecting nothing. But what happens when I do that is that the error dosn't come, but another error comes as a popup:

> An unexpected error has occurred. Try Again. (46F0000A ...

This is when the hotspot cuts off, and I can't search the internet anymore, I think that's because my phone couldn't handle upload of this size though it's the internet.

Then I made a new test app on google play console and uploaded the app there, and there it showed another error, which it hadn't shower before, but I fixed it, it was the SDK version I had one too low, I actually remember shanging that so that was my fault. But on the test application, I could upload the app alfine, besides that, I obviously couldn't because an app already had the same code-name(my original app). But the error didn't show up, although I actually had to upload the aab file 3 times, because of the SDK-version thing, where in the first app, in the start, after one upload and then deleting it, this error came than in the new testing app, it didn't, IDK why?

Now, I've been dealing with this for 3 days now, can anyone help, I can provide more information if needed. Just pleas if you got an answer, send me it :)

Heres my build.gradle file from diarectiry 'myAppName\myapplication\build.gradle' (from line 7 to 15):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

And btw Idk if I have to change something here, but here you go if you need it, its the build.gradle from diarectory 'myAppName\android\app\build.gradle' (from line 18 - 26):

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '4'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '2.0'
}
```

And btw my app is only for Android, nothing to do with Apple, so none of those settings should matter :)

Comment: _"the error still says that I already have a file with version code 1, and it's never been anything else, never 2 or 3, always 1"_ But the error message you put in your question actually says 2.

Comment: @Michael sorry I made a typo. The error was always "Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1" so I just edited my original question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your previous versionCode was 2. You should increment it by 1 to 3. in Manifest file. Also change
build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.my.packageId"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode 2      <-- change this to 3
versionName "1.0"  <-- change this to 2.0
```

}

Comment: The first version was version code 1, and version name 1.0. Then the next version(just somme bug fixes) is versioncode 2, and version name 1.1 in build.gradle. And yea, just tried it out, and the same error occurs. And also I whouldn't have to increse the versionName by a whole number, I could also just do it with .1 or somthing, right?

Comment: The version name is up to you,  but may be you forgot to sync the gradle?

Comment: Yea, I didn't sync gradle, but now, when I do, the error is still there. So there's somthing else going on, you have any idea what?

Comment: Hi, I just tried agein, and I am not sure that I am syncing the build.gradle right, in the last comment I sayd that I wasn't doing it before, and that's right, but resently it has come to my notice that it dosn't work: Because when I changed the version-code and synced, and then build, it just showed the some version from last, the date of the file was the same, so nothing had changed at all, and that makes me think that i'm not syncing it correctly, I just click File/Sync project with gradle file. Any other way of doing it that I'v missed?